# need help replicating jQuery's addClass function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to replicate jQuery's addClass function using plain javascript
So far, I have made this function:

```
function addClass(el,cl){
el.className+=(el.className?' ':'')+cl
}
```

It works well, but It uses this syntax:

```
addClass(element,class)
```

I want it to use this syntax:

```
element.addClass(class)
```

How can I do that?

thanks :)

Comment: There's a free 1 year tutorial on how to make a framework. Take a look it might help http://dailyjs.com/tags.html#lmaf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it a prototype to extend the `Element` class.

```
Element.prototype.addClass = function(cl) {
    this.className+=(this.className?' ':'')+cl;
}
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/3gQg5/)

As minitech pointed out though, this won't work reliably in all browsers (namely IE).

Comment: @minitech: Using this `.htc` hack might work: http://blog.motane.lu/2007/09/20/elementprototype-in-ie/

Answer (score 3):

There is no perfectly safe way to make `element.addClass()` work for all elements when element is a DOM element (not your own object like a jQuery object) in all browsers.  Some frameworks have done this in the past and they have run into enough problems that some are moving away from doing that.  I would not recommend doing it this way.

You are not in the business of browser compatibility or framework creation (not do you want to be) so even though it seems cleaner to extend the DOM objects, I would not recommend it.  jQuery and YUI do not do it this way.  They make a wrapper object that contains both the method and the DOM element reference.

If you want to read of some of the perils, here's a good reference on the subject: [What's wrong with Extending the DOM?](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/).